How to show long text in footer as long with the total number of pages?
I use the following code to add page index and total page number to the output pdf. Before that, I could add long text as footer. I don't know how to get the canvas in PageNumCanvas as in footer. How can I achieve the original effect of long text in footer?
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles['Normal']

def footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    P = Paragraph(f'This is a multi-line footer.  It goes on every page {canvas.getPageNumber()}.  ' * 5, styleN)
    w, h = P.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    P.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, h)
    canvas.restoreState()

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import mm

class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    """
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546511-page-x-of-y-with-reportlab/
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def showPage(self):
        """
        On a page break, add information to the list
        """
        self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def save(self):
        """
        Add the page number to each page (page x of y)
        """
        page_count = len(self.pages)

        for page in self.pages:
            self.__dict__.update(page)
            self.draw_page_number(page_count)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)

        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

        print(type(self), file=sys.stderr)
        print(self.__dict__, file=sys.stderr)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        """
        Add the page number
        """
        page = "Page %s of %s" % (self._pageNumber, page_count)
        self.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
#       self.drawRightString(195*mm, 272*mm, page)
        self.drawRightString(195*mm, 30*mm, page)

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, PageTemplate, Paragraph
doc = BaseDocTemplate(sys.stdout.buffer, pagesize=letter)
# doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='test', frames=Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal'), onPage=footer)])
doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='test', frames=Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal'))])
doc.build([Paragraph(line) for line in sys.stdin], canvasmaker=PageNumCanvas)

